# How to draw color in FireMonkey's TMesh object?

Tags: firemonkey, mesh, c++builder-xe4

I want to draw different color, this is my code:

```
//  Red
Mesh1->Data->IndexBuffer->Length = 6;
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Length = 6;
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Vertices[0] = TPoint3D(0,0,1);
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Vertices[1] = TPoint3D(1,0,0);
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Vertices[2] = TPoint3D(0,1,0);
Mesh1->Data->IndexBuffer->Indices[0] = 0;
Mesh1->Data->IndexBuffer->Indices[1] = 1;
Mesh1->Data->IndexBuffer->Indices[2] = 2;
//  Green
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Vertices[3] = TPoint3D(5,0,1);
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Vertices[4] = TPoint3D(6,0,0);
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Vertices[5] = TPoint3D(5,1,0);
Mesh1->Data->IndexBuffer->Indices[3] = 3;
Mesh1->Data->IndexBuffer->Indices[4] = 4;
Mesh1->Data->IndexBuffer->Indices[5] = 5;
```

How could I do? It must use color map? Just like:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42114

And the TMesh object has 4 color properties:

```
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Color0
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Color1
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Color2
Mesh1->Data->VertexBuffer->Color3
```

what does it mean? How to use it?

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? FMX has changed radically between versions, and therefore the particular version you're using is relevant. (So is the fact you're using Delphi; I've added that tag for you.)

Comment: I use Builder C++ XE4 Update1.

Comment: Once again, I've edited your question to include the relevant information. (You should learn to do so yourself, if you intend to ask for help here. There's an [edit] link right below the tags.)

Comment: thanks for your editing tag.
But what does it mean about "Once again"? Is my question not clear?

Comment: It means "I edited it the first time to add the Delphi tag, and then (again) I edited it to change to the C++ Builder XE4 tag". :-)

Comment: Sorry. And  thanks again.